# Ordenar posicionamento da DIV em CSS

Tags: html, css

Tem alguma possibilidade de eu posicionar a **.divdois** acima da **.divum** somente com o CSS sem precisar trocar a posição do HTML?

```
<style>

.divum {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}

.divdois {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

</style>

<div class="divum"></div>
<div class="divdois"></div>
```

Comment: No caso essa div seria responsiva, não poderia fazer algo chumbado desse modelo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). Ele trabalha como um *flex container*, capaz de ordenar e direcionar os elementos *filhos*. Para utilizá-lo, você precisa determinar `display: flex;` e direcionar de acordo com os requisitos que você quer, no seu caso `flex-direction: column;`, isso configura a ordenação em coluna das suas divs. Por padrão, ele sempre direciona em linha.

Após você aplicar essa configuração no `container`, é necessário adicionar aos elementos *filhos* o parâmetro `order`, definindo com valor numérico a ordem que deseja exibir as suas divs (isso vale também para valores negativos).

```css
.container { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
}

.divum { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  order: 2; 
}

.divdois {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  order: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divum"></div>
  <div class="divdois"></div>
</div>
```

Há outras definições que você pode aplicar dependendo da sua necessidade, no site [origamid](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/) há um ótimo conteúdo sobre o assunto. Você pode ver também no [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) e no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Answer (score 3):

Esta [solução](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/) usa apenas CSS e trabalha com conteúdo dinâmico

```
wrapper   { 
    display: table;
}
firstDiv  { 
    display: table-footer-group; 
}
secondDiv { 
    display: table-header-group; 
}
```

Ou flex-box

```css
/* -- Where the Magic Happens -- */

.container {
  
  /* Setup Flexbox */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  /* Reverse Column Order */
  -webkit-flex-flow: column-reverse;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;

}


/* -- Styling Only -- */

.container > div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container > div:last-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="first">

     Primeira

  </div>
  
  <div class="second">

    Segunda

  </div>
  
</div>
```